# How to solve the "system cannot find the file specified" exception while uploading excel to mysql db

Tags: java, mysql, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to upload the excel using

> Apache POI

and insert into mysql database, trying to locate the source file using "FileInputStream" below is the code for that

```
public class TestApp { 
    //db connections
    ..........
  //below line is throwing an exception 
  FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Sample Excel.xls"));
 HSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input_document);
        /* Load worksheet */
        HSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        // we loop through and insert data
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = my_worksheet.iterator(); 
          while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                  .....
                    .....
         // Add the row to a batch processing - standard batch processing example
        sql_statement.addBatch();
        }
       int[] totalRecords = new int[4];
        try {
                totalRecords = sql_statement.executeBatch();
        } catch(BatchUpdateException e) {
               totalRecords = e.getUpdateCounts();
        }

}
```

but is showing the below exception

```
The system cannot find the file specified exception.
```

full stack trace is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Sample Excel.xls     (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at TestApp.main(TestApp.java:34)
```

I have "Sample Excel.xls" this file in the specified location I tried in multiple ways to solve this problem but i am unable to fix this issue can anyone help me how to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "fix it"? Suppress error/search on another location/exit methods/check file existance before opening/...

Comment: I tried by placing the file in different location but still have same issue

Comment: Try renaming it without space, as there could be two spaces or another character, the hard non-breaking space. As an option in Windows is showing the file extension (".xls") or not, try ".xls.xls". Or ".xlsx" (the other file format). Investigate using `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(File.list("D:\\")));`

Comment: Does `Files.exists(Paths.get("D:\\Sample Excel.xls"))` return `true`? This doesn't appear to be an `apache-poi` issue. If Java cannot see the file then Apache POI cannot use it. Are you running all of this code on your local box? Can you move the file elsewhere and you have the same problem (e.g. "C:\\Sample Excel.xls")?

Comment: I moved the file into my project folder then i am able to find the path of Excel Sheet.